# VHDL: Problema con contadores en sistema de semaforo de 4 vias

Tags: vhdl

Tengo un problema con los tiempos/contadores de un sistema de control para crucero con 4 semáforos, el primer ciclo lo hace de manera correcta y esperada pero al repetir el ciclo (cambiar de s1 a s2) se demora al rededor de 16 segundos más.

Tengo un divisor de frecuencia con un valor de 50,000,000 para que se pueda manejar en escalas de 1s.

Estoy usando las señales fin_cuenta_x para cambiar de estado a estado dependiendo de cada secuencia del crucero. Al igual tengo una señal para representar la cuenta general y, por ultimo, la señal booleana reset_cuenta que coloco en el ultimo estado para así restablecer la cuenta a 0 y que vuelva a contar con el proceso CONT.

El código es el siguiente:

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity semaforo is

    port(     clk : in std_logic;
       reset, aux : in std_logic;
           lights : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
                p : buffer std_logic);
      
end semaforo;

architecture sem of semaforo is
    
    type estado is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13);
    signal estado_actual : estado := s0;
    signal reset_cuenta : boolean := false;
    signal fin_cuenta_5, fin_cuenta_10, fin_cuenta_12, fin_cuenta_17, fin_cuenta_22, fin_cuenta_24, fin_cuenta_29, fin_cuenta_34, fin_cuenta_36, fin_cuenta_41, fin_cuenta_43, fin_cuenta_45 : boolean;
    signal cuenta : integer range 0 to 45;
    constant cuentatope:integer:=50000000;
    
    begin
        
        DIVISOR:process(clk)
        variable temp : integer range 0 to cuentatope;
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                temp:=temp+1;
                if (temp=cuentatope) then
                    temp:=0;
                    p<=not(p);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process DIVISOR;
        
        CONT: process(p)
        begin
            if p='1' and p'event then
                if reset_cuenta then
                    cuenta <= 0;
                else
                    cuenta <= cuenta + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process CONT;
    
        MAQ: process(clk, reset)
        begin
            if reset = '1' then
                estado_actual <= s0;
            elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                case estado_actual is
                    when s0 =>
                        if aux = '1' then
                            estado_actual <= s1;
                        end if;
                    when s1 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_5 then
                            estado_actual <= s2;
                        end if;
                    when s2 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_10 then
                            estado_actual <= s3;
                        end if;
                    when s3 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_12 then
                            estado_actual <= s4;
                        end if;
                    when s4 => 
                        if fin_cuenta_17 then
                            estado_actual <= s5;
                        end if;
                    when s5 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_22 then
                            estado_actual <= s6;
                        end if;
                    when s6 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_24 then
                            estado_actual <= s7;
                        end if;
                    when s7 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_29 then
                            estado_actual <= s8;
                        end if;
                    when s8 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_34 then
                            estado_actual <= s9;
                        end if;
                    when s9 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_36 then
                            estado_actual <= s10;
                        end if;
                    when s10 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_41 then
                            estado_actual <= s11;
                        end if;
                    when s11 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_43 then
                            estado_actual <= s12;
                        end if;
                    when s12 =>
                        if fin_cuenta_45 then
                            estado_actual <= s13;
                        end if;
                    when s13 =>
                        estado_actual <= s1;
                end case;
            end if;
        end process MAQ;
        
        SAL: process(estado_actual)
        begin
            case estado_actual is
                when s0 =>
                    lights <= "0000000000000000";
                    reset_cuenta <= true;
                when s1 =>
                    lights <= "0001001001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s2 =>
                    lights <= "0000001001001100";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s3 =>
                    lights <= "0000001001001010";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s4 =>
                    lights <= "0010001001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s5 =>
                    lights <= "0000001001100001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s6 =>
                    lights <= "0000001001010001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s7 =>
                    lights <= "0100001001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s8 =>
                    lights <= "0000001100001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s9 =>
                    lights <= "0000001010001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s10 =>
                    lights <= "1000001001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s11 =>
                    lights <= "0000100001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s12 =>
                    lights <= "0000010001001001";
                    reset_cuenta <= false;
                when s13 =>
                    reset_cuenta <= true;
            end case;
        end process SAL;
        
        fin_cuenta_5 <= true when cuenta = 5 else false;
        fin_cuenta_10 <= true when cuenta = 10 else false;
        fin_cuenta_12 <= true when cuenta = 12 else false;
        fin_cuenta_17 <= true when cuenta = 17 else false;
        fin_cuenta_22 <= true when cuenta = 22 else false;
        fin_cuenta_24 <= true when cuenta = 24 else false;
        fin_cuenta_29 <= true when cuenta = 29 else false;
        fin_cuenta_34 <= true when cuenta = 34 else false;
        fin_cuenta_36 <= true when cuenta = 36 else false;
        fin_cuenta_41 <= true when cuenta = 41 else false;
        fin_cuenta_43 <= true when cuenta = 43 else false;
        fin_cuenta_45 <= true when cuenta = 45 else false;
        
end sem;
```